# Circular array formula used in iterating months

Tags: c++, circular-reference

Currently I found that using `( starting index + size of array + 1 ) % size of array` will enable me to index the circular array from 0 to N ( size of array - 1 ).

Currently I'm using this to loop `months` from a specific month (i.e 6 = july). But the problem is this approach also print 0 which is not part of the proper month ( 1 - 12 ). I know I can do this with just if else statement but if possible I just want to modify the `( starting index + size of array + 1 ) % size of array` formula to adapt to my needs if it is possible.

Comment: There is no variation of the modulus operator that starts back at 1.  N % N = 0.  Either use an if test as you proposed, or change your range to be 0 - 11.  In my experience, most programs use 0 as the starting value anyway so Jan=0, Dec=11.  That's how arrays work anyway.

Comment: @vicentazo I want to start the index from 0 to 1 ( in short skip 0 ).

Comment: @Moby You *can* redefine the operator (in a mathematical sense) as you seem fit. And you can also redefine it (programmatically, in C++) for custom types to yield a ring 1–12. Whether that’s a good idea is another question (it’s probably a better idea to redefine the months to be enumerated 0–11, but both ways have their pros and cons).

Comment: Also, note that `(starting_index + size_of_array + 1) % size_of_array == (starting_index + 1) % size_of_array`, saving you one addition per reference...

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph As you say, you can't redefine operators for built-in types like int.

Comment: @MobyDisk So? That’s not the same **at all** as claiming that “ There is no variation of the modulus operator that starts back at 1.” – that claim is simply false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as you say `6 = July` then it seems pretty likely that `0 = January` and 0 is in fact a perfectly valid value.

If you mean to say `7 = July` then I would actually suggest simply making your array index from 0-11 instead of 1-12. When changing between interfacing with the user and internal you would do the conversion between zero and one based indexing.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
starting index % size of array + 1
```

Comment: But, assuming `size_of_array == 10`, this would cause issues when `starting_index == 9`... `9 % 10 + 1 == 10`, which may be out of bounds for an array access based on `size_of_array`... The proper operation is `(starting_index + 1) % size_of_array`.

Comment: @twalberg Umm, I also feel a bit strange, but I think OP probably doesn't intend to use the result as an index of array, or actual `size of array` is 13 to use 1-12 as index. In the latter case, I might correct the answer...

Comment: Of course `(size of array - 1)` instead in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an incremental variable `i` and you do something like that `i % N`, you will get circular values from 0 to N-1: 0,1,2,...,(N-1),0,1,2,...,(N-1)

Therefore, if you want to start in 1, you have to add 1 to that result:

```
(i % N) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula you want where
N is the number of elements (12 months) indexed 1..N
n is the "current" element
This generates the indices (indexed from 1) of the 2 adjacent neighbours, wrapping around both ends:

( ( n-1 + N ± 1 ) % N ) + 1

the -1 in (n-1) and the final +1 on the RHS are the index adjustors